# How to create a responsive table using offsetWidth?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, responsive-design

I have an AngularJS application with a table and I want to obtain this scenario:

**First:** I want to a have a fluid table using the **table** bootstrap class;

**Second:** After some javascript changes in the **table head** (reconstruct the th) I want to obtain the same fluid table.

My code (**UPDATED** after reply post): [Pen](http://codepen.io/ptongalex/pen/wMQKKG)

**Javascript**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

app.controller("MainCtrl",['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.currentThWidth = [];
  $scope.convertedWidth = [];
  var helpArray = [];
  $scope.show = function(){
    $scope.reset();
    jQuery('.table').find('th').each(function(index,column){
      helpArray.push(column.offsetWidth);
      $scope.currentThWidth.push('th' + index + ': ' + ' ' + column.offsetWidth + 'px');
    });
  };
  $scope.convert = function(){
    $scope.show();
    for(i in helpArray){
      var temp = (helpArray[i]/(jQuery(window).width()))*100;
      // temp = Translate the offsetWidth in % according to the container's width
      $scope.convertedWidth.push('th' + i + ': ' + temp.toFixed(2) + '%');
      jQuery('table thead th:nth-child' + '(' + i + ')').css('width',temp.toFixed(2) + '%');
    }
  };
  $scope.reset = function(){
    $scope.currentThWidth = [];
    $scope.convertedWidth = [];
    helpArray = [];
    jQuery('table thead th').removeAttr('style');
  };
}]);
```

**Question**

Why don't I get the same width ? I don't have the same table display states. After I execute my javascript function the **th width** is smaller then the initial one. Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not applying your calculations to all the `th`.

In your example, the last `th` never gets updated. I changed your `for(i in helpArray)` to a `jQuery.each()`.

Like this :

```
jQuery('table thead th').each(function(i, tableHead) {
      $scope.convertedWidth.push('th' + i + ': ' + 
      (helpArray[i]/(jQuery(window).innerWidth()))*100 + '%');
      jQuery(this).css('width', helpArray[i] + '/' + 
      jQuery(window).innerWidth() + '*100%');
    })
```

If you notice I'm not using `toFixed()` because this will round the numbers and mess the amount of pixels the browser renders. So the best way will be using the natural browser calculation.

`helpArray[i]/jQuery(window).innerWidth() + '*100%'`

I let the css make the math due to each browser render in different ways.

The output will be something like this:

`<th style="width: 100/1100 * 100%;">`

And the full  code:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.currentThWidth = [];
    $scope.convertedWidth = [];
    var helpArray = [];
    $scope.show = function() {
      $scope.reset();
      jQuery('.table').find('th').each(function(index, column) {
        helpArray.push(column.offsetWidth);
        $scope.currentThWidth.push('th' + index + ': ' + ' ' + column.offsetWidth + 'px');
      });
    };
    $scope.convert = function() {
      $scope.show();
      jQuery('table thead th').each(function(i, tableHead) {
        $scope.convertedWidth.push('th' + i + ': ' + (helpArray[i] / (jQuery(window).innerWidth())) * 100 + '%');
        jQuery(this).css('width', helpArray[i] + '/' + jQuery(window).innerWidth() + '*100%');
      })

    };
    $scope.reset = function() {
      $scope.currentThWidth = [];
      $scope.convertedWidth = [];
      helpArray = [];
      jQuery('table thead th').removeAttr('style');
    };
  }
]);
```

```css
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
table thead tr {
  background: grey;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>th 0</th>
        <th>th 1</th>
        <th>th 2</th>
        <th>th 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="show()">Show offsetWidth</button>
  <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="convert()">Convert to %</button>
  <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="reset()">Reset all widths</button>
  <h2 style="color:#337ab7;">Current table head offset-width: {{currentThWidth}}</h2>
  <h2 style="color:#5cb85c;" ng-if="convertedWidth.length">Converted width %: {{convertedWidth}}</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and explanations sir !!

Comment: @VladRadulescu another quick suggestion on this is, you could move DOM manipulation to directive, controller is not a good place to have DOM manipulation there

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar yes...actually this is a part for an angular directive, but I simplified the problem / stackoverflow thread.